# How can you use INSERT....RETURNING in a JDBC callableStatement

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, callable-statement

Using Callable statements I want to return the serial type column from my database without using a function to do it.

So, I tried to use the following statement to pass as parameter to my `prepareCall` function of my connection to generate a `CallableStatement`.

```
{? = INSERT INTO schema.tbl (col1, col2, col3, col5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) RETURNING col6}
```

Here `col6` has datatype as `serial`.

But this is generating an exception :

> *org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Malformed function or procedure escape syntax at offset 5.*

I feel the syntax used for this statement is wrong. If that is so what could be the correct statement for this?

**NOTE:** I am not able to use `connection.prepareStatement(sql,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);`

**NOTE:** I also know how it can be done by declaring a function in the Postgresql Database Schema. Please do not answer about this method to solve the problem.

I specifically request that please answer by stating how the statement can be changed so that it can work with `CallableStatement`

Comment: Why do you insist on using `CallableStatement`? It's the wrong tool for the problem. Use a regular `PreparedStatement.execute()` then use `PreparedStatement.getResultSet()`. You can even use `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` with such an `insert` if you are not interested in the number of rows that were inserted.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually I have to pass the statement as a parameter to a function that generates a `CallableStatement` which is declared in the super class of this current class. Also do you also mean to say that it is not possible without declaring a function in the database?

Comment: You can't use a `CallableStatement` for anything else then calling functions (or procedures). And even that is not needed in Postgres because you can call a function by simply running `select function_name(?,?)` with a regular `PreparedStatement` (a **lot** easier in opinion than the convoluted syntax for a `CallableStatement`)

Comment: You might want to try without the malformed call escape around it (so **only** the `insert .. returning ..`), it might just work (but I don't expect so).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The call escape is technically optional (it is just to provide a database independent way of calling a stored procedure).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel when I removed the escape I got an exception stating: **This statement does not declare an OUT parameter.  Use { ?= call ... } to declare one.**

Comment: Then you are out of luck, you either need to wrap it in a stored procedure (function), or you need to change the code so you can use a prepared statement instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From all the comments I have received on this question simply point to the direction that it is not possible to use `INSERT .... RETURNING` statement as a parameter to a `CallableStatement`.

It can either be used as a parameter `PreparedStatement` using `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` as the second parameter as I stated earlier in the question.

Or it can be used by wrapping it in an Stored Function in the Postgresql Database Schema and then using `{? = CALL <STORED FUNCTION>}` as parameter in the `CallableStatement`.